# How is the gasPrice generated in ethereum

Tags: gas-price

while I execute `eth.gasPrice` via the geth console,it returns the current default gasPrice `20322509741`, so

1. how is this default value generated
2. will it changes now and then according to the market
3. transaction creators hope the lower gasPrice while the miners opposite，how to reach an agreement
4. miners could start the geth with the parameter --ask to set the lowest gasPrice，will the setting changes during the runtime?

Answer (score 1):

> how is this default value generated

This is a median based on the value used in recent blocks.

> will it changes now and then according to the market

Yes, it changes.

> transaction creators hope the lower gasPrice while the miners opposite，how to reach an agreement
>   miners could start the geth with the parameter --ask to set the lowest gasPrice，will the setting changes during the runtime?

It's a market mechanism.

Miners set the minimum price at which they are prepared to accept transactions. This can be either set on the command line when the node is started or changed while the node runs. Transaction creators set the maximum price which they are prepared to pay for their transaction to be mined.

Miners want to maximize their revenue. There's a cost to accepting a transaction, because a bigger block will take longer to propagate across the network and get validated by other miners, resulting in a greater risk that the block will be orphaned. There's also a maximum limit to the gas that can be used in the block, beyond which it is invalid, so if they fill that up they want to fill it at a high price, not a low price. However, if they set their price too high then they'll lose money be turning away too many paying transactions.

Comment: 1. Could you tell me the rule that the default value of gasPrice changes following to, both at the geth starting and the runtime. 
             2.For example, a minner set its --ask  5E+11,  it  has accepted all the transactions it could,  but the gas used has not reached to the maximum.So it will turn down the gasPrice at this time to accept more transactions?
         3. How to set the maximum limit to the gas that can be used in the block?